# Parsing usercontent into repository. Which approach is better?

Tags: c#, deserialization

after reading about many different design patterns i got a question about my current project and I hope somebody can help me.

My project takes different user files as input and transforming them into a repository of objects for easy use.

For example:

```
Userfile A with the content: 
"id:a" - "value1:contentA1" - "value2:contentB1" 
"id:b" - "value1:contentA2" - "value2:contentB2" 
"id:c" - "value1:contentA3" - "value2:contentB3"
```

Now i see two different approaches to parse this file into objects (which is better?):

**1)**

We got a entity class:

```
public class UserContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

A service which takes a line of the user file and parses it into the object:

```
public class UserContentParser
{
    public UserContent ParseUserContent(string content)
    {
        // ...
        // splitting the content
        // ...
        return new UserContent
                            { 
                                ID = id,
                                Value1 = value1,
                                Value2 = value2
                            };
    }
}
```

A ParseController:

```
public class ParseController
{
    private Repository _repository = new Repository();
    private UserContentParser _userContentParser = new UserContentParser();

    public Repository StartParsing(File userFile)
    {
        // ...
        // reading file
        // ...
        foreach(var contentLine in userFileContent)
        {
            _repository.AddUserContent(_userContentParser.ParseUserContent(contentLine));
        }
    }
}
```

The other approach I see is the following:

**2)**
This approche just consits of two classes (no service class):

```
public class UserContent
{
    public UserContent(string content)
    {
        // ...
        // splitting the content
        // ...
        ID = id;
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ParseController
{
    private Repository _repository = new Repository();
    private UserContentParser _userContentParser = new UserContentParser();

    public Repository StartParsing(File userFile)
    {
        // ...
        // reading file
        // ...
        foreach(var contentLine in userFileContent)
        {
            _repository.NewUserContent(contentLine);
            // in this method the repository creates the 
            // new UserContent(contentLine)
        }
    }
}
```

The projects also contains some plugins, which are getting a reference to the repository to work with the containing objects.

Which approach is better here? Is there maybe a better alternative? And what happens if other dependencies are needed to parse the user content? Is it ok if the entity depends on services or is it better to have no dependencies in entity objects? And even one more question, is the UserContent class a DTO because it is used to parse user content into it an passing it to other plugins?

I hope someone can help me with my many questions.

Regards,
Gerrit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have many question and they are hard to anwser because they depend on a lot on your context and that is implied to you, but not to us. Also, I think you are worrying too much upfront and thinking "what if" too much when you should not.

However, as a general advice you should follow [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and put each responsabilities in it's own class so having the parser as a separate class makes sense. Having this in a separate class will allow you to extract a *Parser* interface from it and have multiple implementations and manage parser's dependencies if you ever get to that.

You should worry about the "what if" problems when they come to you or when you *know* that they will come to you based on previous experience, not before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The SRP is the reason why i would prefer a ParseController, too.

One last question: Is it right that the UserContent class is a DTO in this example (Because of parsing data into it and passing it to plugins)? Or is it an business entity?

Comment: It depends on your context. If you are thinking about separating the parser, then the parser becomes a different application and define it's contract exposing it's own set of classes. If they are highly dependable then the parser can export your business entities directly. It all comes down to how much abstraction you want to add to the app.